# R Count duplicates between two dataframes

Tags: r, duplicates

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. They both have a column 'ID'. For each row in DF1, I would like to find out how many duplicates of its ID there are in df2 and add the count to that row. If there are no duplicates, the count should return as 0.

```
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      ID     a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1_234     1     1
# 2     1_235     1     2
# 3     2_222     1     1
# 4     2_654     1     2




# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      ID     a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1_234     1     1
# 2     1_235     1     2
# 3     1_234     1     1
# 4     3_234     1     2
```

Comment: Please provide data sample using `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

Your data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1_234","1_235","2_222","2_654"),
                  a = c(1,1,1,1),
                  b = c(1,2,1,2))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1_234","1_235","1_234","3_235"),
                  a = c(1,1,1,1),
                  b = c(1,2,1,2))
```

Edit: considering only the `ID`s:

```
output <- left_join(df1,
          as.data.frame(table(df2$ID)),
          by = c("ID" = "Var1")) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = ifelse(is.na(Freq), 0, Freq))
```

Output:

```
     ID a b Freq
1 1_234 1 1    2
2 1_235 1 2    1
3 2_222 1 1    0
4 2_654 1 2    0
```

Comment: How may I amend this to only look at the ID? I am not interested in the other variables being the same, just the ID.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `semi_join` and `n()` to get the count of duplicates:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  semi_join(df2, by="ID") %>% 
  summarise(duplicates_df1_df2 = n())
```

Output:

```
  duplicates_df1_df2
1                  2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it with a simple `sapply()` and base r (no extra packages).

```
df1$count <- sapply(df1$ID, function(x) sum(df2$ID == x))
```

Comment: I am actually only interested in the IDs - not the other values. Apologies for not specifying. However, this takes a long time, is there another efficient method?

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `subset` + `aggregate`

```
subset(
    aggregate(
        n ~ .,
        rbind(
            cbind(df1, n = 1),
            cbind(df2, n = 1)
        ), function(x) length(x) - 1
    ), ID %in% df1$ID
)
```

gives

```
     ID a b n
1 1_234 1 1 2
2 2_222 1 1 0
3 1_235 1 2 1
4 2_654 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `outer`

```
df1$count <- rowSums(outer(df1$ID, df2$ID, FUN = `==`))
df1$count
[1] 2 1 0 0
```